# Including JRE with steam application

Tags: java, portability

I have a application that I would like to include the jre with, because I cannot rely on the user having java installed. The program runs on the command line, started up with a .bat file.

What is the most clean, safe, and legal way to include the jre?
The options I have looked at so far are:

Install scripts, launch4j bundling, and literally just including the java install files

I haven't been able to actually get any of these to work with my command line application.

I would prefer if someone could find a way to do this from eclipse but am open to other programs and methods. My product is only for windows and I am using windows, so other use cases may be discarded when posting your answer.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm#JSDPG583

Comment: [jmod](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jmod.html) and [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html) will create an image tree with a stripped-down JRE included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into this: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net
It bundles everything into an .exe